# Which GCC security features should I use to secure a network daemon?

Tags: linux, security, gcc, compiler-flags

I'm writing a C++ network daemon for Linux which by its nature will have to listen on the public internet.

Which GCC switches should I use to enable security features to make it harder for a possible attacker to exploit bugs in my program ?

Currently I'm using the stack protector. (GCC: -fstack-protector, LD: -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now).

Which other features should I enable (besides all warnings etc. about issues in my program) ? What about PIE ?

How do I check if the feature is actually active in the running process ?
I found [lsexec](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2008/06/position-independent-executables.html), but for example it doesn't show any process using PIE on my system, so I'm not sure how reliable it is.

**Update:**

So far I found the hardening guides from [Debian](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2008/06/position-independent-executables.html) and [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain/CompilerFlags?action=show&redirect=CompilerFlags) and this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544512/what-is-the-most-hardened-set-of-options-for-gcc-compiling-c-c). But nothing on how to check what is actually active in an executable, yet.

Comment: Be aware that no set of compiler options will make it the least bit difficult to write insecure code. (You probably already know that.)

Comment: I am fully aware of that, but its also a fact of life that even the best code has some bugs left. So it is good to be prepared.

Comment: If compiler flags could do it all, then there wouldn't have exploits all over.  Even ASLR and DEP fail at times.

Comment: I'm not asking for  "do it all". I'm asking how to enable whats available, beyond the best programming I can do. So how do I enable ASLR and DEP on Linux and what else is there ?